# How do I typecast when object property name is different from json name in typescript?

Tags: typescript

How do I typecast when object property name is different from json name in typescript ?

Here is the code

```
// my class
export class processGroup {
    processGroupName: string;
}
```

The json which I get

```
[{ groupName: "g1"}]
```

In the service code I need to map the json into array of typed variable.

```
.map((response: Response) => <processGroup[]>response.json())
```

Can I do it without changing of property name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing property name you can map your object to relevant object

```
  .map((response: Response) =>  
     <processGroup[]>response.json()
     .map(function(elem){ return { processGroupName: elem["groupName"]} });
```